# cvs2svn changes binary files

Tags: binary, mime-types, cvs2svn

I'm using cvs2svn to migrate from [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) to [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29).

I've noticed a problem with my binary file after the conversion was completed.

I'm using auto-props file, which is very helpful.

After the conversion I took the file from CVS and compared it to the same file from SVN.
The file is binary. Using [WinMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinMerge), I see that there is a difference between the files.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using cvsnt? If you do, cvs2svn doesn't understand that your file is binary, because cvs and cvsnt flag binary files differently. It is simple enough to write a program that converts this. I had to do that.

Now, if you have a binary file that isn't marked as binary in cvs, or it is marked using the cvsnt syntax, and the file contains patterns like "$Id" or "$Date", then Subversion will substitute those patterns when you check out the files. Usually that means your binary file will get corrupted.

How to convert: If the file contains "kopt b;" assume it is binary, although technically a file may be binary in some revisions and not in others. For all binary files, insert "expand @b@;" before "symbols" near the top of the file, so the header looks something like this:

```
head    1.1;
access;
expand  @b@;
symbols
```

When you do this, be careful not to change anything in the rest of the file, e.g. line endings.

Comment: can you specify how to convert a file?